# Javascript form validation - ONLY the first character must be numeric

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm stuck on one small part of my form - I'd like to make it so just the first character of the street address field is numeric, the rest can be anything. I have fiddled with using indexOf as well as reg ex.. I get close, but not quite.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
window.onload=function()
{
    document.forms[0].onsubmit=function()
    {

        for(i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++)
        {
            //alert required field
            if(this.elements[i].className.indexOf("required") != -1)
            {
                if(this.elements[i].value == "")
                {
                    alert("required field");
                    this.elements[i].focus();
                    return false;
                }   

            } 


            //username requirements
            var userLength = document.getElementById("user")

            if((userLength.value.length < 5) || (userLength.value.length > 10))
            {
            alert("username must be between 5-10 characters");
            return false;
            }


            //email address requirements
            var emailMust = document.getElementById("email")

            if((emailMust.value.indexOf("@") == -1) || (emailMust.value.indexOf(".") == -1))
            {
                    alert("email must contain proper characters");
                    return false;
            }


            //address requirements
            var address = document.getElementById("address")
            var regex = new RegExp('/^[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]$/');

            if(address.match(regex))
            { 
                alert("address must begin with a number");
                return false;
            }



            //birth year requirements
            var birthYear = document.getElementById("birth")

            if(isNaN(birthYear.value))
            {
                alert("birth year must be a number");
                return false;
            }


        } 

    } 
}
```

here`s my html portion:

```
<form action="#">

<p><label for="user">Username:</label>*</p>
<p><input type="text" class="required" id="user"></p>

<p><label for="email">Email Address:</label>*</p>
<p><input type="text" class="required" id="email"></p>

<p><label for="address">Street Address:</label></p>
<p><input type="text" id="address"></p>

<p><label for="birth">Year of birth:</label>*</p>
<p><input type="text" class="required" id="birth"></p>

<br>
<input type="submit">
<p><i>* required field</i></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use:

```
var regex = new RegExp('/^[0-9]{1,}[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/');
```

Here's how {} works:

```
a{3}    Exactly 3 of a
a{3,}   3 or more of a
a{3,6}  Between 3 and 6 of a
```

I'd also point out that your pattern isn't accounting for spaces that come after the number. For example, it would not match 123 Rod Street. I'd also include a space in your set (right before the letter a)

For example:

```
new RegExp('/^[0-9]{1,}[ a-zA-Z0-9]*$/');
```

Update::

I'd leave off the forward slashes because since you're passing it as a string it will get escaped automatically!!

```
new RegExp('^[0-9]{1,}[ a-zA-Z0-9]*$');
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a great modification, however I see an error on line 51 with address.match is not a function?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to use address to get getElementById("address") from my form... makes sense in my head, but I keep getting a syntax error

Comment: You try to match the element with the regEx, not the value of it!

Comment: @amapeli you need to match it with the value ie. `address.value.match(...)` because match is a method of strings.

Answer (score 4):

Change the following line

```
var regex = new RegExp('/^[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]$/');
```

to

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[0-9]');
```

Since your requirement is that **just the first character of the street address field is numeric, the rest can be anything**, your regular expression should concern itself with the first character only. If you must specify another character class, it shouldn’t be as narrow as `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Remember that a valid address may contain characters like comma, hyphen, space and so on.

Comment: What's the `+` for? The 2nd expression matches numbers anyway.

Comment: @clentfort Thank you for pointing it out. I’ve modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is a better and clean solution for 1st character validation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try converting the first char into it's ordinal value and comparing it to the range of ASCII number literals.

```
var addressValid = address.value.charCodeAt(0);
addressValid = (addressValid >= 48 && addressValid <= 57)
```

The value addressValid will be true if the first char is a number (0-9). All simple and without regular expression.

Of course you could do all this by directly accessing `address.value.charCodeAt(0)` in an `if` but this is for demonstration purpose, therefore more verbose.